# Issue on lapply when assigning a variable

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, lapply

I have an R code that uses the lapply inorder to display the values of the each TrendDateRange.  I am not getting what I should expected

Here is a sample code. Please note that this is only sample code that I have to include on my shiny app which uses the lapply. The numoftrends in my shiny is a selectinput. But for this test, I am assigning it myself.  How do  I code this in R since I am new to this. Thanks for looking into this.

```
 trendDateRange1 <- c("2011-01-01","2011-12-31")
 trendDateRange2 <- c("2012-01-01","2012-12-31")
 trendDateRange3 <- c("2013-01-01","2013-12-31")

 numoftrends  = 1;

 lapply(1:numoftrends, function(i) {
   trend.period <- paste0("trendDateRange", i) ;
 })
```

Comment: Using get? `trend.period <- get(paste0("trendDateRange", i))`

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. One question though. Do I need to use this code in shiny if the trendDateRange comes from the dateRangeInput 
         lapply(1:numoftrends, function(i) {
                 trend.period <- input[[get(paste0("trendDateRange", i))]] ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trendDateRange1 <- c("2011-01-01","2011-12-31")
trendDateRange2 <- c("2012-01-01","2012-12-31")
trendDateRange3 <- c("2013-01-01","2013-12-31")

numoftrends  = 3

lapply(1:numoftrends, function(i) {
  trend.period <- get(paste0("trendDateRange", i)) 
})
```

EDIT:

Something like above, although a example of desired output would be needed from poster.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. One question though. Do I need to use this code in shiny if the trendDateRange comes from the dateRangeInput 
         lapply(1:numoftrends, function(i) {
                 trend.period <- input[[get(paste0("trendDateRange", i))]] ;

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your time. Appreciate it!